# Using object of a class as parameter of other class

Tags: java

I am working on creating an ATM machine as a java project for one of my -very- Java Beginner's courses and I am confused about how to use an object of a class as a parameter of another class. I know how to use inheritance but in this case, User and BankAccount are at the same level and that also confuses me in this case.

This is my code so far :

BankAccount CLASS

```
package atm;

public class BankAccount {
    public double balance; 
    private int accountNumber = 333220; 
    public String user; 
    public BankAccount(){
        balance = 0; 
    }

    public BankAccount(double balance, int accountNumber, User user){ 
        this.balance = balance;
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber; 
        this.user = user;  // HERE, THE CONSOLE TELLS ME I CAN'T CONVERT USER TO STRING. USER HAS ONLY STRINGS AS PARAMETERS. DO I NEED TO CAST? HOW WOULD I DO IT? 

    }

    public void accountNumber(){
        accountNumber++;
    }

    public int getAccountNumber(){
        return accountNumber;
    }

    public void deposit (double amount){
        balance += amount; 
    }

    public void withDraw(double amount) {
        balance -= amount;  
    }

    public double getBalance (){
        return balance;  
    }

    public void transfer( BankAccount other,double amount){
        withDraw(amount);
        other.deposit(amount); 
    }

     }
```

user class :

```
package atm;


public class User {


    public String name;  
    public String lastName; 
    private  int dOB; 

    public User (String aName, String aLast){
        name = aName; 
        lastName = aLast; 

    }

      public String getName(){
          return name;   
      }

      public String getLastName(){
          return lastName; 
      }

       public int getDOB(){
           return dOB; 
       }


      public String getUniqueKey(int dOB){
          String uniqueKey = name.substring(0,1) + name.substring(name.length() -1) + dOB + lastName.substring(0,1) + lastName.substring(lastName.length()-1); 
          return uniqueKey.toLowerCase(); 
      }



}
```

Comment: Mistake here : public String user. Change it by public User user

Comment: You're declaring the `user` field as type `String` (`public String user`), but it should be declared as `User user`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `user` instance must have the data type `User` not `String`.

It must look like this:

```
public class BankAccount {
    public double balance; 
    private int accountNumber = 333220; 
    public User user;
```

---

**The detailed answer:**

`Java` provides two types of data representation: `primitive types` and `reference types`.

Java has eight built-in data types, referred to as `Java primitive types`.

These eight data types represent the building blocks for Java `objects` because all Java objects are just a complex collection of these primitives. (`short`, `int`, `double`, etc..)

**Reference types hold references to objects (instances of classes)**.

Unlike primitive types that hold their values in the memory where the variable is allocated, references don't hold the value of the object they refer to.

Instead, a reference points to an object by storing the memory address where the object is located.

Instance variables can be both reference type and primitive type **in your example you are using a reference type that represent the account property "User"**.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, Ahmad! It -obviously- worked and now I won't forget to check my data types before assigning them to objects. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Well what you're trying to do is giving a String object reference a User object, that's why "THE CONSOLE TELLS ME I CAN'T CONVERT USER TO STRING" happens.

what you should do is simply replace this line: `public String user;`
with this: `public User user;` so the object reference matches the object type itself.